# Show icon map -- Lightning map LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-map

Hello guys I am working on a LWC that contains a lightning-map. The apex controller brings to the javascript wire method a list of different records that come from different objets. so for this case I made the followed Wrapper:

```
public class WrapperData {
    @AuraEnabled public String name{get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled public String city{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String country{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String postalCode{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String street{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String objectName{get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled public String id{get;set;} 
}
```

and in my javascript I am getting the next list:

```
  [{"city":"A",
    "country":"X",
    "id":"****",
    "name":"***",
    "objectName":"Contact",
    "postalCode":"84764",
    "street":"Street A"
   },
    {"city":"B",
    "country":"V",
    "id":"******",
    "name":"*****",
    "objeto":"Account",
    "postalCode":"*****",
    "street":"Street B"
   }]
```

So I want that in my map based on the field objectName the icon in the map to be different.
So I made this:

```
directionsListWired = [];
mapMarkers = [];
@wire(getListFromApex)
wiredRelatedRecord(result){
    const{data,error} = result;
    if(data){
        this.directionsListWired = data;
        this.fillMapMarkersStructure();
    }else if (error) {
        this.isLoading =false;
        this.records = undefined;
        this.error = error;
    }
}

fillMapMarkersStructure(){
    var ijson;
    var pathGoogle = 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z';

    this.mapMarkers = this.directionsListWired.forEach(direction => {
        
        if(direction.objeto.includes('Account')){
            ijson = {
                location: {
                    Street: direction.street,
                    City: direction.city,
                    PostalCode: direction.postalCode,
                    State: direction.state,
                    Country: direction.country
                },
                title: direction.name,
                icon : 'standard:account',
                mapIcon : {
                    path: pathGoogle,
                    fillColor: 'pink',
                    fillOpacity : 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 0,
                    scale: 0.10,
                    anchor: {x: 122.5, y: 115}
                }
            }
            this.finalList(ijson);
            
        }else{
            if(direction.objeto.includes('Contact')){
                ijson = {
                    location: {
                        Street: direction.street,
                        City: direction.city,
                        PostalCode: direction.postalCode,
                        State: direction.state,
                        Country: direction.country
                    },
                    title: direction.name,
                    icon : 'standard:account',
                    mapIcon : {
                        path: pathGoogle,
                        fillColor: 'green',
                        fillOpacity : 0.8,
                        strokeWeight: 0,
                        scale: 0.10,
                        anchor: {x: 122.5, y: 115}
                    }
                }
                this.finalList(ijson);
            }else{
                if(direction.objeto.includes('Case')){
                    ijson = {
                        location: {
                            Street: direction.street,
                            City: direction.city,
                            PostalCode: direction.postalCode,
                            State: direction.state,
                            Country: direction.country
                        },
                        title: direction.name,
                        icon : 'standard:account',
                        mapIcon : {
                            path: pathGoogle,
                            fillColor: 'blue',
                            fillOpacity : 0.8,
                            strokeWeight: 0,
                            scale: 0.10,
                            anchor: {x: 122.5, y: 115}
                        }
                    }
                    this.finalList(ijson);

                }else{
                    ijson = {
                        location: {
                            Street: direction.street,
                            City: direction.city,
                            PostalCode: direction.postalCode,
                            State: direction.state,
                            Country: direction.country
                        },
                        title: direction.name,
                        icon : 'standard:account',
                        mapIcon : {
                            path: pathGoogle,
                            fillColor: 'black',
                            fillOpacity : 0.8,
                            strokeWeight: 0,
                            scale: 0.10,
                            anchor: {x: 122.5, y: 115}
                        }
                    }
                    this.finalList(ijson);
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
mapMarkersToReturn = [];
finalList(event){
    this.mapMarkersToReturn.push(event);
    console.log('this.mapMarkersToReturn' + JSON.stringify(this.mapMarkersToReturn));
}
```

But the problem is that the list and the icons in the map are not showing I am getting a blank component... I do not know what am I doing wrong.

My html looks like this:

```
<template>
<lightning-map
                map-markers={mapMarkers}
                markers-title='Data List'
                list-view='visible'
                >

</lightning-map>
```

the map is not showing nothing. Could anybody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your mapMarkers variable is never set to your values.

.forEach() is an iterator function. It does not return a new array. The return value only allow you to exit the current iteration for the next.

You want .map() to return a new array.

```
let array = [0,1,2,3,4];
let result = [];

result = array.forEach(a => { return a+1; });
console.log(result);  // undefined

result = array.map(a => { return a+1; });
console.log(result);  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I also tried this approach but I still in the same point. Could you put an other example?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the browser console if there is any error in mapMarkerObject you will see blank component. You should be receiving invalid mapMarker on browser console. add branching accordingly in below return block to have specific values and icon

```
 this.mapMarkers = this.directionsListWired.map(mapItem => {
        return {
            location: {
                City: 'San Francisco',
                Country: 'USA',
                PostalCode: '94105',
                State: 'CA',
                Street: 'The Landmark @ One Market, Suite 300',
            },
            value: 'location001',
            title: 'The Landmark Building',
            description: 'The Landmark is considered to be one of the city&#39;s most architecturally distinct and historic properties', //escape the apostrophe in the string using &#39;
            icon: 'standard:account',
    
        };
    });
```

Comment: I am receiving a blank component but I am returning exactly the same as you. I updated the post

Comment: Can you please post the json.stringify of  this.mapMarkers the object you are preparing is not in correct structure